# How to remove spaces between bar in grouped bar charts, in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js, frontend

I am facing the issue removing the space between bar. If the bar data is 0 or null. I want to remove the space from red series, which doesn't contain any data in vanilla.

It is possible ?

Here's the actual code :

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = {
  labels: ["Chocolate", "Vanilla", "Strawberry"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Blue",
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    data: [3, 7, 4]
  }, {
    label: "Red",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    data: [4, 0, 5]
  }, {
    label: "Green",
    backgroundColor: "green",
    data: [7, 2, 6]
  }]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    barValueSpacing: 20,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPse9.png)

Comment: It's hard to help without the code

Comment: @AdamKniec I have added the code